# How to configure download folder in Android Studio

Tags: linux, android-studio-2.3

I'm pretty keen on getting to run my first app in a emulator in Android Studio. But to be able to do that I need to set up a AVD and for that I need to download a system-image through Android Studio.
How ever it looks like my space on my root is too small for that:
https://pasteboard.co/GIXNiRX.png

Is there a way to change the download folder inside Android Studio?

Or is the only way to solve this by increasing the space on root in some way?

Best regards
Fredrik

Answer (score 0):

Turn out that I needed to upgraded to Android Studio 3.1.2 and since I use a too old computer I am aiming to run my app on a real device.
Best regards
Fredrik